# My code throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, repeat

I need to write code that will write all negative and positive numbers from array, i did that, other part of code is to write all duplicate numbers and how many times do they repeat , it works, but it also writes error, im new to java, so if anyone can help with my code, thank you

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87};
        int cntPoz = 0, cntNeg = 0;

        //for petlja broji pozitivne i negativne clanove array-a
        for (int a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {
            if (array[a] > 0) {
                cntPoz++;
            } else if (array[a] < 0) {
                cntNeg++;
            }
        }

        // kreiranje novih nizova 
        int[] pArr = new int[cntPoz];
        int[] nArr = new int[cntNeg];
        //for petlja iz array-a premjesta sve pozitivne brojeve
        cntPoz = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] > 0) {
                pArr[cntPoz++] = array[i];
            }
        }

        //for petlja iz array-a premjesta sve negativne brojeve
        cntNeg = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] < 0) {
                nArr[cntNeg++] = array[i];
            }
        }

        //sortiranje i ispis nizova
        Arrays.sort(pArr);
        Arrays.sort(nArr);
        System.out.println("Originalni niz je : \n" + java.util.Arrays.toString(array) + "\n");
        System.out.println("Niz pozitivnih brojeva : \n" + java.util.Arrays.toString(pArr) + "\n");
        System.out.println("Niz negativnih brojeva : \n" + java.util.Arrays.toString(nArr));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        int[] arr2 = new int[array.length];
        Arrays.sort(array);

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            arr2[i]++;
            if (i + 1 < array.length) {
                if (array[i] == array[i + 1]) {
                    arr2[i]++;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j<array.length; j++){
        for (int i = j+1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (arr2[i] > 0 && array[i]==array[i+1]) {
                System.out.println("Duplikati su : "+array[i] + " i pojavljuju se " + arr2[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
```

**ERROR:**

this is the output :

```
Originalni niz je : 
[12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87]

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 13
Niz pozitivnih brojeva : 
[12, 12, 23, 43, 43, 545]

Niz negativnih brojeva : 
[-999, -87, -55, -22, -4]


Duplikati su : 0 i pojavljuju se 2
    at assignment.Assignment.main(Assignment.java:65)
Duplikati su : 12 i pojavljuju se 2
Duplikati su : 43 i pojavljuju se 2
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Please post the error's stack trace in the question

Comment: @GurwinderSingh

Comment: I updated my code, output is last

Comment: You should `for (int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++)` in second last outer for loop instead

Answer (score 3):

I think that the error is here:

```
if (arr2[i] > 0 && array[i]==array[i+1]) {
```

At the last iteration, i+1 exceeds the maximum dimension of `array`.

Maybe you want to stop the cycle at the previous iteration in order to allow the final comparison, like this:

```
for (int i = j+1; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
```